# is there a limitation on the number of bit in register which I have an event on?

Tags: specman

I have a 64bit register and want to define an event when it changes,something like:
event clk is change('~/top.reg')@sim;

Is there a limitation on the number of bits in top.reg? and if yes, how can I do the same for 64bit reg?

Answer (score 0):

You can sample only the bits that interest you in the register instead of all the register, which will be costly in performance.
if you want to sample all the register you can divide the sample into 2 X 32 bits.

Answer (score 0):

You can also define list of event ports and connect each list item to the specific register's bit.